# All Superspeed USB peripherals connected to Raspberry Pi 4 shows up as USB 2

Tags: pi-4, usb3

I'm running the official Raspberry Pi OS on Raspberry Pi 4B - 8GB RAM, whenever a USB 3 capable device is plugged into the USB 3 ports, it enumerates as USB 2.

OS Details:

- Release date: February 21st 2023
- System: 64-bit
- Kernel version: 5.15
- Debian version: 11 (bullseye)
- Size: 816MB

I installed all updates and upgrades and eeprom updates and it didn't fix the issue: 
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo lsusb -v -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
```

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: `a USB 3 capable device` - such as?